# OpenERP - not getting list of customers from res.partner on tree view

Tags: python, odoo

I am a new to both Python and OpenERP.

The following code loads into OpenERP with no errors; however, I am not seeing any data from res.partner as I am expecting to.

Can anyone see what the problem is in my code?

```java
    class delivery_forcast(osv.osv):

    _name = "delivery.forcast"
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns={
        'delivery_state': fields.selection([
            ('scheduled','Scheduled'),
            ('delivered','Delivered')],
                'Delivery Status', readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange'),
        'est_delivery_date': fields.date('Estimated Delivery Date', readonly=False),
        'container_size': fields.integer('Container Size', help='Container size to be filled in gallons',readonly=False),
    }

delivery_forcast()
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_delivery_forcast_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">delivery.forcast.tree</field>
            <field name="model">delivery.forcast</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Partner List">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="est_delivery_date"/>  
                    <field name="container_size"/>   
                    <field name="delivery_state"/> 
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>


        <record id="show_delivery_forcast_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Delivery Forcasts</field>
            <field name="res_model">delivery.forcast</field>
            <field name="view_type">tree</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
            <field name ="domain">[('customer','=',1)]</field>  
        </record>


        <menuitem name="Delivery Forcasts" id="menu_delivery_forcasts" action="show_delivery_forcast_tree"/>

    </data>

</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inheriting a model and creating another model, the new model will not have the data from inherited model. Here you inherited 'res.partner' and created new model 'delivery.forcast'. So data will be stored in new table 'delivery_forecast'. You have to specify the table name of the inherited model in order to show all the data. ie,
You have to give like this
    _name = 'delivery.forcast'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _table = 'res_partner'
Then it will show all the data in res_partner

Answer (score 0):

In your tree view, please add the field customer as an invisible field. then check it

Comment: I added invisible customer field to tree view and there was no change in how the module works.